# "Database '[DatabaseName]' already exists. Choose a different database name" when login failed by user

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Trying to update existing database with recent migrations. And following exception is thrown:

> "Database '[DatabaseName]' already exists. Choose a different database name"

The aim is not to create a new database but update existing database with the recent migrations.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was **login failure** to database. Database was restored from backup and a user was dropped. Therefore the user could not access the database and somehow it tries to create a new database... I wish  the error message was '**Login failed for user 'whatever''**